# SQL Server : how to write a SQL Select query to search a data from a column contains delimited data?

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT ID, 
        CAST('EDIT' AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS 'test',
        CAST([dbo].[SC_GetVersionedFieldValue](ID, '{8DBF084C-E575-4739-B37A-F732F72CFF69}') AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS 'City',
        CAST([dbo].[SC_GetVersionedFieldValue](ID, '{32ED6082-1145-4331-9D29-F47E19090A0A}') AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS 'Sectors' 
    FROM [dbo].[Items] WHERE [TemplateID] = '{000C7660-E35B-4734-B1DA-A42A79A7B827}') 
    mytable 
WHERE [City] like 'l%' 
OR [Sectors] LIKE '%{20090D52-4C76-4C93-A249-F6E0883F4663}%' 
OR [Sectors] LIKE '%{FAE9FCB9-8D1C-439E-BA6C-00804C58361E}%' 
OR [Sectors] LIKE '%{844C2884-4E6A-4F38-9DE4-7CCF7DDF06C6}%'
```

I need to retrieve the rows where city name start with ‘some alphabet’ AND sectors should be in (id1, id2, id3…n) not OR. Some of the ids were located in between two ids that is delimited data (refer the picture). Any advice?

[image]

Comment: **DON'T PUT DELIMITED DATA IN COLUMNS!!**

Comment: Data source from third party CMS system. Their system captures the data with this format.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to write a multistatement table-valued function that translates your multi-valued column into multiple rows.  (see the documentation for [CREATE FUNCTION](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186755.aspx).)

Once you have that function, you can then call it via CROSS APPLY.

(And, as Joel Coehoorn noted in a comment, you shouldn't store data like this in SQL Server.  Instead, moving the GUID's for "Sectors" to a foreign table.  Or, at least, an XML field.)

Answer (score 0):

I Don't understand your need in where clause but **try this**

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT ID, 
        CAST('EDIT' AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS 'test',
        CAST([dbo].[SC_GetVersionedFieldValue](ID, '{8DBF084C-E575-4739-B37A-F732F72CFF69}') AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS 'City',
        CAST([dbo].[SC_GetVersionedFieldValue](ID, '{32ED6082-1145-4331-9D29-F47E19090A0A}') AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS 'Sectors' 
    FROM [dbo].[Items] WHERE [TemplateID] = '{000C7660-E35B-4734-B1DA-A42A79A7B827}') 
    mytable 
WHERE [City] like '[A-Z]%' --'[a-z]%'
and (
        [Sectors] LIKE '%{20090D52-4C76-4C93-A249-F6E0883F4663}%' 
        OR [Sectors] LIKE '%{FAE9FCB9-8D1C-439E-BA6C-00804C58361E}%' 
        OR [Sectors] LIKE '%{844C2884-4E6A-4F38-9DE4-7CCF7DDF06C6}%'
        )
```

HOPE GOT SOME IDEA.